# how to change Mysql server hostname

Tags: mysql, database

I run my service in docker-compose. And MySQL host name is “mysql”, when I develop in my computer, MySQL host name is “localhost”.

Now I want to change my computer MySQL hostname to “mysql”. So I can connect MySQL on my computer by `mysql+pool://root:password@mysql/test_db`.

Please help me, I find solution spend lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to separate this connection string setting to an environment variable.

If you really want to use mysql, you can modify your OS's hosts file (e.g. for macOS or many linux distros, it should be /etc/hosts).

and put `127.0.0.1    mysql` at the end of the file.